# How to show field label in error message Python WTF

Tags: python, wtforms

WTF Form :

```
class ReplyForm(BaseForm):
    max_reply_count    = IntegerField(label=_("Max Reply Count") ,default="10",validators = [v.NumberRange(max=10), v.InputRequired(message=_('Max Reply Count is required'))])
    sleep    = IntegerField(_("Sleep") ,validators = [v.NumberRange(min=60), v.InputRequired(message=_('Sleep is required'))])
```

WTF generate errors like that

```
["Not a valid integer value", "Number must be at most 10."]
```

Is that possible generating error messages by default like this?

```
["Max Reply Count is not a valid integer value", "Max Reply Count must be at most 10."]
```

I dont want to define messages by pass params

```
v.NumberRange(max=10,message=_("Max Reply Count must be at most 10."))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :

```
class BaseForm(Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def allErrors(self):
        allErrors = list()
        for fieldName,errors in self.errors.iteritems():
            for m in errors:
                allErrors.append(getattr(self,fieldName).label.text + " : " + str(m))
        return allErrors
```

Example usage :

```
.
.
.
print wtFormObj.allErrors()
```